# Python NumPy: Importing data with only one column from a csv into 2D array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to import this data from a csv file into a 2D array:

```
0
1
1
0
```

This is my code:

```
Y = np.genfromtxt("output_data.csv", delimiter=",")
```

I am looking for a structure like this:

```
[[ 0. ]
 [ 1. ]
 [ 1. ]
 [ 0. ]]
```

but instead it comes out like this:

```
[ 0.  1.  1.  0.]
```

As soon as I add a second column to the data it comes out the correct way. I am looking for a general solution so I don't have to program any special cases for a single column of data.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Y = np.loadtxt("output_data.csv", delimiter=",", ndmin=2)
```